# Failing functional test on GAE, Django, WebTest

Tags: django, google-app-engine, webtest

I've got a GAE/Django project and I'm trying to make a functional-test enviroment work with WebTest, the project layout is as follows:

```
/gaeroot
  /djangoroot
    wsgi.py
    urls.py
    ...
    /anapp
      urls.py
      ...
      /tests
        test_functional.py
```

wsgi.py (generated by GAE's version of django-admin.py django1.5):

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoroot.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

test_functional.py:

```
import unittest
import webtest
from djangoroot.wsgi import application

class TestHomePage(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(application)

    def test_get_method_ok(self):
        response = self.testapp.get('/path')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 200, response)
```

The failing test message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
line 14, in test_get_method_ok
self.assertEqual(response.status_int, 200, response)
AssertionError: Response: 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://localhost:80/path/
```

Why is throwing a redirect code to the same path, the only thing I can think of is that some code of django is responsible for the redirection because as you can see from the directory tree I have a two level url configuration.

On the other side, why is using port 80? when I test it on the browser it shows an 8080 port, and it shouldn't use a port at all since `WebTest` it's supposed not to use a port at all since it's testing the WSGI interface right?.

Top level urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^path/', include('djangoroot.anapp.urls')),
)
```

App level urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('djangoroot.anapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home', name='anapp_home'),
)
```

The browser shows the corret page on the same url, I took the WebTest example from google's support pages, so the problem should be the GAE/Django interop.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be on the `django.conf.urls.url` function since I tested the root `urls.py` file and it worked for the root path `/` with no redirection, but it did redirected me with a path other than the root, I could find nothing that seemed being redirecting my urls on the Django source files.

I found an alternative on the `Webtest` documentation:

```
resp = self.testapp.get('/path')
resp = resp.maybe_follow()
```

with the `maybe_follow` method you eventually get the final page.

**Edit**

Finally I found the problem in this line:

```
response = self.testapp.get('/path')
```

replace it with this:

```
response = self.testapp.get('/path/')
```

It looks like `Django` redirects the urls to the propper path with the `/` at the end.

Comment: Aha! The Trailing '/'. Thank you!